# Linux: How to use the same interrupt to be handled by more than one CPU in parallel

Tags: linux, interrupt, multicore

I want to use **one interrupt** to trigger actions for **more than one core simultaneously**.

What I have:

- A multicore SoC running Linux on it.
- A timer built in on the SoC platform, external to the CPUs.
- Few available interrupt lines

What I've tried (and work fine for one CPU):

A kernel module from user space by:

- finding the right irq line irq_of_parse_and_map()
- request_irq()
- start the timer by writing directly to its registers using __raw_writel()
- change affinity to other cpu with irq_set_affinity_hint()

What I've tried with no success (for more than one CPU using the same interrupt):

- Similar steps as above.
- use request_percpu_irq(), enable_percpu_irq() and free_percpu_irq() instead of request_irq().

However request_percpu_irq() is always returning -22.

**Question:**
Is it the right approach? if not, how could I get this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
At the end I used **on_each_cpu()** function to trigger actions per core within the isr.